# WPF: Change LineHeight property of RIchTextBox

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, richtextbox

First I must say that I am a beginner at .net and WPF. So now I am having a problem setting a LineHeight property of a RichTextBox. But if I write LineHeight="10" in XAML file it says : **The member "LineHeight" is not recognized or is not accessible.** I would like to find a way to set it like in TextBox.

XAML code:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <RichTextBox Width="auto" LineHeight="12"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="14" Padding="0" Margin="0" Background="Transparent" Name="LabelContent" IsReadOnly="true" BorderThickness="0" IsDocumentEnabled="True" FontFamily="Calibri"/>
    <Label HorizontalAlignment="Right" Padding="0,0,0,0" Name="LabelDate" Margin="0" FontSize="10" Foreground="{Binding TimeTextBrush}" Content="Feb Tue, 12:35" />
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: `This article is for Windows Phone 8 developers`. Are you developing for Windows Phone?

Comment: What Greg just mentioned (seconds before I could lol). Here is the [documentation for RichTextBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.richtextbox?view=netframework-4.7.2) I believe you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this woks:

```
 <RichTextBox Block.LineHeight="2"/>
```

Or this:

```
<RichTextBox>
    <RichTextBox.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Paragraph}">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,10,0,0"/>
        </Style>
    </RichTextBox.Resources>
</RichTextBox>
```

Or this:

```
RichTextBox rtb = new RichTextBox();
rtb.SetValue(Paragraph.LineHeightProperty, 1.0);
```

Comment: Ok. But I will let the others there too. Maybe it helps someone.

Comment: I think the second one is for setting the padding to the around the text in RichTextBox

Comment: I think it is to set the top margin of a paragraph in a rtb